# Calculate equipment cost across multiple columns

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to generate reports based on weekly production data. I have two tables: Table A (`Production`) and Table B (`cost`).

[image: Example tables here]

As you can see, there are several different pieces of equipment, each with its own cost. I am trying to calculate the total costs for the week broken down into both worktype and equipment type.  I have [mocked up a little table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG0fH.png) to show what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the bad design of your `Production` table. This will force you to create 3 separate `JOIN`s between the two tables to get to the result you need, but that's where you start. `JOIN` `cost` to `Production` using `EQ Code=EQ1`, `EQ Code=EQ2`, `EQ Code=EQ3` for the three `JOIN`s. Then it is just a matter of doing the appropriate math with `Sum` and `GROUP BY`s to get to the result you want.